# Android app for uploading some file to the developer's drive

Tags: android, android-studio, google-drive-android-api

I want to create an android application which takes a file from internal storage and saves it to google drive of the app's developer(i.e. my drive) and not the user's drive.

What are the procedures to do so?

Some examples would be great?

Which gradle dependencies i have to add, which api i have to enable in android developer's site, which api to use for network transactions (retrofit/asynctask/volley/okhttp)?

Some running tutorials or examples?

Edit
If we cannot do it, please provide some MBASS(mobile backend as a service) api that can enable me to do so? i want to save a folder structure with files and videos to developer's cloud and can be viewed online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official api to upload data from app to third party drive. Only you could save data in the users drive. But you can create application folder inside user drive account which is hidden from user.